# How to handle Thread Start-Stop-Start on same button click

Tags: android, multithreading, buttonclick

I need to start a thread which is working for a loop. Ex. I want to set a loop which will count till 100.And I want to do it using thread.But I want to start thread on a button onclick action. When Button clicked thread start and it will count 1.and when I press button again it will count 2 from thread.Each button click increase a number from loop from thread.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

**So finally I came up with the solution that worked for me**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

volatile boolean toExit = false;
Thread t;
private int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (toExit = true) {
                for (i = i; i <= 10; i++) {
                    Log.w("Number i ", "is --->" + i);
                    i = i + 1;
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                toExit = false;
            }
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            t.start();
            Log.w("Thread ", "Start!!!");
        }
    });
}
}
```